# Export all gridview pages to excel

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, gridview, export-to-excel

I am trying to export my gridview list to an excel sheet. Everything is working fine but the gridview is exporting only the first page, when I have multiple pages.

This is the code I used:

```
Public Sub Export(ByVal fileName As String, ByVal gv As GridView)    
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear()
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename={0}", fileName))
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel"
    Dim sw As StringWriter = New StringWriter
    Dim htw As HtmlTextWriter = New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
    gv.AllowPaging = False
    GetData()
    Dim table As System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table = New System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table
    table.GridLines = gv.GridLines
    For Each row As GridViewRow In gv.Rows
        PrepareControlForExport(row)
        table.Rows.Add(row)
    Next
    table.RenderControl(htw)
    '  render the htmlwriter into the response
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sw.ToString)
    HttpContext.Current.Response.[End]()
End Sub
```

Comment: You use : For Each row As GridViewRow In gv.Rows ... so all rows from gridView  are parsed !

Comment: Try to use For r = gv.Rows.Count -1 to 0 Step -1 , insted For Each  row As GridViewRow In gv.Rows ....

Comment: @CristiC777 I am getting error: `value of type integer cannot be converted to control`

Comment: at what line number you get this error ?

Comment: You're approaching this all wrong. You shouldn't think about it as exporting a grid view. You should think about it as exporting the underlying data. And you shouldn't render the gridview to HTML, because then you've just created an HTML file masquerading as Excel. Programs won't like that. Instead, you should generate an actual Excel file with EPPlus, NPOI, Open Office XML SDK, or a similar libary.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's a better polished version of excel exporting that i use:
(Some of the code might be in C#, do the conversion to VB or else tell me to do it.

```
    Public Sub Export(ByVal fileName As String, ByVal gv As GridView) 
{

            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.Charset = your charset//"Windows-1253";
            Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            string attachment = "attachment;" + filename;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
            Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(@"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"">");

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<font style='font-size:10.0pt; font-family:Calibri;'>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<BR><BR><BR>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<Table border='1' bgColor='#ffffff' " +
              "borderColor='#000000' cellSpacing='0' cellPadding='0' " +
              "style='font-size:10.0pt; font-family:Calibri; background:white;'> <TR>");
            int columnscount = gv.Columns.Count;

            for (int j = 0; j < columnscount; j++)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<Td style='background-color: #C0C0C0;' align=" + "center" + ">");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<B>");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(gv.Columns[j].ToString());
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</B>");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</Td>");
            }
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</TR>");
            foreach (DataRow row in gv.Rows)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<TR>");
                for (int i = 0; i < gv.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<Td align=" + "center" + ">"); ;
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(row[i].ToString());
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</Td>");
                }

                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</TR>");
            }
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</Table>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</font>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```